# Fixed point property for the projectivization of manifold of fixed rank matrices

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, fixed-point-theorems

Let $M$  be the manifold of  all matrices in $M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ with fixed rank $0<k<n$. The projectivization of $M$ is denoted by $PM$.

> Does $PM$ satisfy fixed point property?

Comment: Sometimes yes (e.g., $k=0$), sometimes no (e.g., $k=n$).

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev For non critical $k$?

Comment: What is "fixed point property"?

Comment: @Sasha $X$ has fixed point property if  for  every  continuous map $f$ on $X$ there is  a  $b\in X$  with $f(b)=0$.

Comment: I think you meant $f(b)=b$ here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually no (check the precise dimensions yourself). In fact, just the map $M\mapsto GM$ for $G\in GL(n)$ typically has no fixed points. For $GM=\lambda M$ implies that the columns of $M$ are eigenvectors of $G$ (with the same eigenvalue $\lambda$). Thus, it suffices to assume that $G$ has no eigenspace of dimension $\ge k$.